# How to traverse mesh vertices based on their location?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, mesh, traversal, point-clouds

I am using [Point Cloud Free Viewer](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/utilities/point-cloud-free-viewer-19811) to visualize Point Clouds in Unity. It has a script and it parses .off files and creates meshes without triangulating. However, the code creates multiple meshes since its index format is 16bit. I modified the code for utilizing 32 bit format and i have a mesh with 2 million points:

[image]

What i want to do is creating a grid like geometry and color this point cloud based on point density. I want to find a rough volume of this point cloud by multiplying differences between max and min x,y,z values and divide this volume into equal boxes. Each of these boxes will be colored based of how many points they contain. I would be happy if someone can offer me a lead. I tried KDTree approach but it is a bit slow since i have 2 million points. I also tried sorting points before creating the mesh but it takes too much time as well. Is there a way to traverse mesh vertices based on the location without visiting all vertices considering they are indexed randomly? I believe i am looking for a solution like `mesh.bounds.contains()` but i do not know if a method like spatial search exists.

Comment: Do it the other way around. Instead of looping over the boxes and asking what points are in the box, loop over the points and increment the counter for the respective box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might visit this question later i found a really fast solution based on Nico's comment. I am traversing whole points by parsing my scan file using this script

```
 for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
    {
        buffer = sr.ReadLine().Split();

        points[i] = new Vector3(float.Parse(buffer[0]) , float.Parse(buffer[1]) , -float.Parse(buffer[2]) );

        //Finding minX, minY, minZ
        if (points[i].x < minX)
            minX = points[i].x;
        if (points[i].y < minY)
            minY = points[i].y;
        if (points[i].z < minZ)
            minZ = points[i].z;
        //Finding maxX, maxY, maxZ
        if (points[i].x > maxX)
            maxX = points[i].x;
        if (points[i].y > maxY)
            maxY = points[i].y;
        if (points[i].z > maxZ)
            maxZ = points[i].z;

    }
```

Here is my and variables i use with it`FindPointIndex` function.

```
    deltaX = maxX - minX;
    deltaY = maxY - minY;
    deltaZ = maxZ - minZ;
    gridCountX = Mathf.CeilToInt(deltaX / gridSize);
    gridCountY = Mathf.CeilToInt(deltaY / gridSize);
    gridCountZ = Mathf.CeilToInt(deltaZ / gridSize);
    Resolution = gridCountX * gridCountY * gridCountZ;
    Histogram = new int[Resolution];

 int FindPointIndex(Vector3 point)
{
    //Finds the grid index of the point 
    int index = Mathf.FloorToInt((point.x - minX) / gridSize) + ((Mathf.FloorToInt((point.z - minZ) / gridSize)) * gridCountX)
           + Mathf.FloorToInt((point.y - minY) / gridSize) * gridCountX * gridCountZ;
    if (index < 0)
    {
        index = 0;
    }
    return index;
}
```

Then i can traverse the points again to increment index for each of them to see how many points each grid holds like this:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < numPoints; i++)
    {
        Histogram[FindPointIndex(points[i])]++;                                      
    }
```

At the end using this histogram i can color the point cloud with another loop.

Answer (score 1):

Not really, a full solution, more a hint towards a direction I would pursue: divide your vertex pool into smaller groups first, I.e into cubes (seperate meshes maybe), precalculate this, then you only have to search within a much smaller region, after an initial search for a set of cubes that neighbour (or touch) your region.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. My problem is vertices are parsed from a file and subsequent ones are not necessarily adjacent to each other or even close sometimes in the real world geometry.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me like you want an [octree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree).

First, load all of the points into memory (2 million points really isn't that many - assuming doubles, that's 2,000,000 * 3 * 8 bytes ~= 45 MB). While you are parsing the file and loading the points into memory, record the min and max x, y, and z coordinates. You can then build your octree which bounds that volume in N*LogN. Then, for each of your grid volumes, you can very quickly query the tree to get only the points in that region. I'm pretty sure this is the most efficient way to do what you want.

I would suggest checking the [quadtree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree#Query_range) article for its implementation of `queryRange` to see how this would be done. An octree is just a 3-d implementation of a quadtree, so the underlying code is more or less the same (with each node containing 8 children instead of 4).

Comment: Thank you i did some more research and everything leads to octree. I will dig into it and edit my question.